# Pass sec (simple event correlator) input directly

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu, input

is there any way to pass the **sec** (simple event correlator) directly like below:

```
$ sec -conf=exmaple_config.conf -input="The text which i want to process"
```

I have a c program that i have to pass some string to **sec** to process it and receive the result again. This is it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* string_to_prcs = foo();
    char command[200];
    sprintf(command, "sec -conf=example_config.conf -input=\"%s\"", string_to_prcs);
    system(command);

    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: `#include <stdio>` → `#include <stdio.h>`, `void main()` → `int main(void)`. And by directly, you mean without a character array?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Thanks @CoolGuy for correction. The main question is the way to pass sec input directly